# With Python, how to scrape the descriptive text of a link from a Google search?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

In python3 I have this script to scrape the first screen of a Google search:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

nome = '"ALDEANNO CAMPOS"'
nome = nome.replace(' ', '+')
cargo = 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL'

busca = f'https://www.google.com.br/search?q={nome}+{cargo}+ditadura'

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

browser.get(busca)

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
browser.close()

page = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rc"})

for link in page:
    href = link.find("a")['href']
    texto = link.find("a").text
    print(href)
    print(texto)
    print("---------------")
```

The program shows or captures the href link and a descriptive text of the link, that is, the name of the page. But I also want to extract the phrase that is below the Google search link

For example, on this page (https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&ei=DrSNW8r3E4urwgS977WYDA&q=ALDEANNO+CAMPOS+deputado+federal+ditadura&oq=ALDEANNO+CAMPOS+deputado+federal+ditadura&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.1933260.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.U9iFnwXwzpk) the texts:

"Aug 24, 2018 - Perfil completo do candidato ao cargo de Deputado Federal Aldeanno Campos que concorre pelo PRP nas Eleições 2018 no Pará."

"Relacionamos a seguir os senadores e deputados federais brasileiros cassados conforme as .... Epílogo de Campos · Costa Rego · Recife, PE, PTB-PE (1962) ..."

"Francisco Luís da Silva Campos (Dores do Indaiá, 18 de novembro de 1891 — Belo Horizonte, ... Em 1921 Francisco Campos foi eleito deputado federal pelo PRM, estreando na ... Armadas, dos preparativos que levariam à ditadura do Estado Novo, instalada por um golpe de estado decretado em novembro de 1937."

And so on

Please, does anyone know how I can capture this final text that lies below the link?

Example of how it appears with the name "CORONEL FERES" - print (link) -  (could not display html code)

> PSL Itapema - Posts | Facebookhttps://www.facebook.com/PSLitapema17/posts/1638801189535968General Mourão apoia o pré-cadidato a *Deputado Federal Coronel Feres*. Confira: 37 Views .... Há uma *ditadura* silenciosa que não podemos permitir. Bom dia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add that inside your loop, see below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

nome = '"ALDEANNO CAMPOS"'
nome = nome.replace(' ', '+')
cargo = 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL'

busca = f'https://www.google.com.br/search?q={nome}+{cargo}+ditadura'

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

browser.get(busca)

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
browser.close()

page = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rc"})

for link in page:
    href = link.find("a")['href']
    texto = link.find("a").text
    body = link.find('span', attrs={'class': 'st'}).text
    print(href)
    print(texto)
    print(body)
    print("---------------")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:

```py
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
    snippet = result.select_one('#rso .lyLwlc').text
```

Have a look at [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Also, you don't actually need to use `selenium` since it slows down scraping time a lot.

Make sure you're using [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) if **not** using `selenium` otherwise Google will block request eventually since the default `user-agent` in `requests` library is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and will block a request.

---

Code and [example using `requests` and `beautifulsoup` in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py%5C):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "ALDEANNO CAMPOS DEPUTADO FEDERAL ditadura", # query
  "gl": "br",                                       # country to search from
  "hl": "pt"                                        # language
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com.br/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  snippet = result.select_one('#rso .lyLwlc').text

  print(f"{title}\n{link}\n{snippet}\n")

-------
'''
Deputado Federal Jefferson Campos - Portal da Câmara dos ...
https://www.camara.leg.br/deputados/74273
Deputados podem apresentar emendas ao Orçamento da União, ou seja: sugerir ao Poder Executivo gastos específicos, para atender demandas da comunidade que ...
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case that you only need to iterate over strucutured JSON string and get the data you want fast, rather than making everything from scrach and maintain the parser over time or figuring out why certain things don't work as they should.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "google_domain": "google.com.br",
  "q": "ALDEANNO CAMPOS deputado federal ditadura",
  "hl": "pt",
  "gl": "br",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
   print(f"Title: {result['title']}\nSummary: {result['snippet']}\nLink: {result['link']}\n")

-----
'''
Title: Girão critica prisão de Silveira e vê 'ditadura da toga' - Senado ...
Summary: En pronunciamento nesta terça-feira (23), o senador Eduardo Girão (Podemos-CE) criticou a decisão da Câmara dos Deputados que confirmou por ...
Link: https://www12.senado.leg.br/noticias/materias/2021/02/23/girao-critica-prisao-de-silveira-e-ve-ditadura-da-toga
...
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.